# mySQLAdapter deployment fails and ends up with the error "Adapter deployment failed: Adapter 'mySQLadapter' contains errors"

Tags: mysql, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have been working on worklight for past few days and now am trying to make my application which connects to a database. Below are the screenshots of the:

1) Worklight\server\conf\worklight.properties

[image]

2) mySQLAdapter-impl.js

[image]

3) mySQLAdapter.xml!

[image]

Whenever I try to deploy mySQLAdpater file it says "Adapter deployment failed: Adapter 'mySQLadapter' contains errors". I don't have any idea about this.

Comment: Add the full error message you get (screen shot). Have you included a db2 driver in the the server\lib folder?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried myself yet, but in `worklight.properties` maybe you should change the following so that they would match?

```
 -    training-jndi-name=${custom-db.1.jndi-name}
 -    custom-db.1.relative-jndi-name=jdbc/worklight-training

 +    training-jndi-name=${custom-db.1.relative-jndi-name}
 +    custom-db.1.relative-jndi-name=jdbc/worklight-training
```